# Is there an operator for comparing undefined or null types?

Tags: javascript, comparison

Sorry if the title made it unclear, but I've been wondering, is there an operator for comparing types like `null` and `"null"`?
We all know that:
`"1" == 1` returns true.
and
`"1" === 1` returns false.
But when I try to do something like:
`undefined == "undefined"`, for me, it returns false, even though I am not using `===`.
Why does this occur? Is there an operator for comparing `undefined` and `"undefined"`, or `null` and `"null"`?, etc...

Comment: well i think the reason is one of them is of type string and another one is of type undefined. `type coercion`. when js turns strings to numbers. that is why "1" == 1 is true. and the reason "1" === 1 is false is because this time the data type is compared too.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `String(x) == "undefined"` / `String(x) == "null"`. But I can't see a good reason to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question in the title, no there isn't - JavaScript does not generally examine the semantic content of strings - "use strict" placed at the beginning of code to invoke strict mode execution is the exeception.

Note that the `typeof` operator is a convenience operator which does **not** return the data type of its operand in all cases - function objects are of (JavaScript) data type "Object", and `null` is of (JavaScript) data type "Null".

`"undefined"` is a string value with specific content. It is not equal to `undefined` (the one and only value with data type "Undefined") or `null` (the one and only value with data type "Null").

There is however an automatic type conversion between `null` and `undefined` which causes the non-strict equality operator to treat them as being equal, often used with a negation operator:

```
 if( value != null) {
     // proceed knowing value isn't `undefined` or `null
 }
```